# Android: DialogFragment Style ignored

Tags: java, android, datepicker, dialogfragment

I have a button on my activity which calls the following function:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.datePickerTheme);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="datePickerTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately whatever I put into the styles.xml it does not change the design of the date picker.

Anyone an idea what's wrong?
Thanks!